# Hanging moving gestures (Left/normal/right/up/normal/down) using mpu9150 sensor

Tags: arduino, sensors, android-sensors, mpu, tilt-sensor

We tried (Arduino+mpu9150) using gestures LEFT-NORMAL-RIGHT, UP-NORMAL-RIGHT.

We can able to get these gestures, but not accurately.

Its HANGING in middle, and sometimes values are also Incorrect.

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Please check complete code for an ++attachment.

### CODE:

```
void guesture() {


  //LEFT & RIGHT
  //Starting Accelerartion condition

  if ( diff_yaw < -250)
  {
    diff_yaw = -(360 + diff_yaw);
  }
  else if (diff_yaw > 250)
  {
    diff_yaw = 360 - diff_yaw;
  }


  if ((aaReal.y < -1500) && (flag1 == false) && (flag2 == false) ) {
    old_time1 = new_time;
    old_yaw = new_yaw;
    flag1 = true;
  } else if ((aaReal.y > 1000) && (flag2 == false) && (flag1 == false)) {
    old_time1 = new_time;
    old_yaw = new_yaw;
    flag2 = true;
  } else if (aaReal.z > 400 && flag11 == false) {
    old_time = new_time;
    flag11 = true;
  } else if (aaReal.z < -400 && flag22 == false) {
    old_time = new_time;
    flag22 = true;
  }

  if ((aaReal.y > 1000) && (flag1 == true)  && (flagZ1 == false)) {
    flagZ1 = true;
  } else if ((aaReal.y < -1500) && (flag2 == true) && (flagZ2 == false)) {
    flagZ2 = true;
  } else if (aaReal.z < -400 && flag11 == true) {
    diff_time = new_time - old_time;
    flag11 = false;
    if (diff_time < 2000 ) {
      flag33 = true;
      old_time = new_time;
    }
  } else if (aaReal.z > 400 && flag22 == true) {
    diff_time = new_time - old_time;
    flag22 = false;
    if (diff_time < 2000 ) {
      flag33 = true;
      old_time = new_time;
    }
  }

  if ((aaReal.y < 1000) && (flagZ1 == true)) {
    flag1 = false;
    flagZ1 = false;
    diff_yaw = new_yaw - old_yaw;
    diff_time = new_time - old_time1;
    if (diff_time < 2000)
    {
      flagN = true;
    }

  } else if ((aaReal.y > -1500) && (flagZ2 == true)) {
    flag2 = false;
    flagZ2 = false;

    diff_yaw = new_yaw - old_yaw;
    diff_time = new_time - old_time1;
    if (diff_time < 2000)
    {
      flagN = true;
    }

  }

  if (flagN == true) {

    if (Iposition == 0 && diff_yaw > 0) {                   //Right
      Iposition = 1;
      flagR = true;
    } else if (Iposition == 0 && (diff_yaw) < 0 ) {         //Left
      Iposition = 2;
      flagL = true;
    } else if (Iposition == 1 && (diff_yaw) < 0 && (diff_yaw) > -25) { //Right-Normal
      Iposition = 0;
      flagNL = true;
    } else if (Iposition == 1 && (diff_yaw) < -25) {       //Right-Left
      Iposition = 2;
      flagL = true;
    } else if (Iposition == 2 && (diff_yaw) > 0 && diff_yaw < 25) { //Left-Normal
      Iposition = 0;
      flagNL = true;
    } else if (Iposition == 2 && diff_yaw > 25) {          //Left-Right
      Iposition = 1;
      flagR = true;
    }
  }
  if (flagN == true  || flag33 == true) {
    if (flagR == true) {
      Serial.println("POSITION : RIGHT");
      flagR = false;
    } else if (flagL == true) {
      Serial.println("POSITION : LEFT");
      flagL = false;
    } else if (flagNL == true) {
      Serial.println("POSITION : NORMAL");
      flagNL = false;
    } else if (Ipos == 0 && pO >= 20 ) {
          Ipos = 1;
          Serial.println("POSITION : UP");
        } else if (Ipos == 0 && pO <= -20 ) {
          Ipos = 2;
          Serial.println("POSITION : DOWN");
        } else if (Ipos == 1 && pO <= 10 && pO >= -10 ) {
          Ipos = 0;
          Serial.println("POSITION : NORMAL");
        }  else if (Ipos == 1 && pO < -5  ) {
          Ipos = 2;
          Serial.println("POSITION : DOWN");
        } else if (Ipos == 2 && pO >= -10 && pO < 0) {
          Ipos = 0;
          Serial.println("POSITION : NORMAL");
        } else if (Ipos == 2 && pO > 0  ) {
          Ipos = 1;
          Serial.println("POSITION : UP");
        }
    flagN = false;
    flag33 = false;
  }


}
```

Comment: This is pretty arduino specific, you might get a better answer on the arduino SE.

Comment: I Aishwarya, I recommend you try to narrow your search (and ours) to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may find your solution just by creating one.

Comment: Could any one plz help me.